# $|\exp(iRe^{i\theta})|=\exp(-R\sin\theta)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 116 he writes:

[image]

Why is the last equality true?

Comment: $|e^{x+iy}|=e^x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$
|e^{iRe^{i\theta}}| = |e^{{iR(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)}}| = |e^{{iR\cos\theta}}e^{-R\sin\theta}| = |e^{-R\sin\theta}|,
$

since $R\cos\theta$ is real, hence $|e^{{iR\cos\theta}}| =1$

Answer (score 0):

Because for $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ :

$$e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}\implies\left|e^{x+iy}\right|=|e^x|\,|e^{iy}|=e^x$$

since $\;|e^{iy}|=|\cos x+i\sin x|=\sqrt{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}=1\;$

And in your case:

$$e^{iRe^{i\theta}}=e^{iR(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}=e^{-R\sin\theta}e^{iR\cos\theta}$$